# How to mass replace structure in PostgreSQL database schema?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm hoping a PostgreSQL expert can help out with this one ;) To avoid liability problems we've been asked to replace all instances of the word "patient" with "client" in our database **schema**. We do, however, use PGAdmin.

**The catch:** our database "guy" is currently on vacation.

Given this is not a small change, what is the most efficient and effective way to change the schema and minimize disruption? Does PGAdmin do this efficienty or will I need to go the SQL route?

Thanks!

Comment: That _seems_ like a pointy-haired thing to have to do.  I hope someone has a good answer, but I'm more intrigued by the _why_ of it than I am by the answer.

Comment: @WayneConrad one of our clients has heavy involvement in development and is used as a reference case. given that their service provides transportation for cancer treatments, they asked us to change all terminology in code and documentation so that there's no association with actual medical practice.

Comment: @WayneConrad p.s. love the reference to dilbert ;)

Comment: Thank you.  And thank you also for the interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql is capable of changing column and table names:

```
alter table patients rename to clients;
alter table visits rename column patient_id to client_id;
```

You can group these changes in a transaction, so that all either happen at once, or not at all:

```
begin;
alter table this...
alter table that...
...
commit;
```

Databases have programs that use them, and these programs are frequently tied to the names in the schema.  Are your client programs such that they automatically adapt to schema changes?

Comment: Thanks! yes we can adapt our client software to the schema changes, and luckily there's no need to make data changes, only schema. this will be tested locally and then pushed via a database evolution and GIT.

Comment: Take care about table names and columns names used in views, stored functions and triggers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the luxury, a really simple way would be with `sed` and `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -s [arguments to connect to your database] | sed 's/patient/client/g' > new_structure.sql
```

This (potentially) gets you a new schema that has every instance of "patient" changed to "client," but it doesn't do much for your data, so you'll have to dump and load the data separately, which you may not have the ability to do easily. Wayne's answer is better, but either way, you probably have extensive application changes to coordinate at the same time.

I would delay if possible, this isn't a change you should take lightly.

Comment: luckily i can test everything locally and then push the changes using GIT. i agree i'll probably go with Wayne's method but if I was more experienced with PGSQL i'd probably go this route. thanks!

Comment: amendment: i also realized Wayne's method will be easier to manage in a database evolution since the changes can be split apart, but the contribution helped me learn nonetheless!